# How to identify a class without anything inside it (empty class)

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class like below

```
public class ClassDemo {
/*
   private String getData() {
      String s = "testClass";
      return s;
   }
*/
}
```

In the above class the only method it has was commented out. This is literally useless. Since I have a lot of classes in a package it's not easy to identify as there is no dependency on this class or methods inside this class.

I use Maven to build. Is there a way to identify such classes?

I understand it's possible to achieve that using eclipse. But is there a way to detect that in build tools like Maven, Ant etc?

Comment: http://www.ucdetector.org/

Answer (score -1):

The class named java.lang.Class has a lot of goodies available, such as `getFields()`, `getConstructors()`, `getMethods()`, `getClasses()`, `getInterfaces()`, `getAnnotations()`... etc. If the length of the array is zero, then there is none in that class.

Edit: Just use the `getClass()` method in java.lang.Object

Comment: And this was downvoted because....?